# What is the standard way to store images and data with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

We need to store user data on a database. We also need to store content/info data and images to be dynamically served to the users via a PWA.

When I tried creating the Firestore DB for the users, Firebase warned me:

"Enabling Cloud Firestore will prevent you from using Cloud Datastore with this project, notably from the associated App Engine app"

If this means that we cannot use Firestore and Storage together, what is the standard way to have a database and image content to be served to the users, with Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Datastore is not Cloud Storage.  They are different Google Cloud products.  If you enable Firestore, you will still be able to use Storage just fine.